# Compiling Binaries with Clozure Common Lisp

Tags: compilation, executable, common-lisp

Given a simple program such as the following, how would you:

1. compile it as a seperate image file to be loaded by the implementation, and what command line arguments would you use to load it?
2. Compile it as a standalone binary that can be loaded and run as is.

   *Note: I tried adding ":prepend-kernel t" when saving the application only to have the follow error thrown.*

   ```
   Error: value NIL is not of the
   expected type REAL. While executing: 
   CCL::<-2, in process Initial(0).
   ```
3. How would you supress the welcome message?

   **The Program**

   ```
   (defun main ()
     (format t "This is the program.")0)
   ```

**Edit**

Hate to answer part of my own question, but I found it none the less.

After the function has been loaded type the following to compile it:

```
(ccl:save-application "app")
```

This creates an image file. To load it by passing it to the implementation type (note: the 'ccl' binary is in my system path);

```
ccl -I app
```

To run a top level function pass it as a parameter

```
ccl -I app --eval (main)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

See the Clozure Common Lisp documentation under [Saving Applications](http://ccl.clozure.com/manual/chapter4.9.html#Saving-Applications)

**Compiling and Loading Lisp files**

You can compile a file named `/foo/bar.lisp` by calling

```
 (compile-file "/foo/bar.lisp")
```

This will create a *fasl* (FASt Load) file, which contains native code.

You can load the compiled file, the fasl file, with the function `LOAD`. `LOAD` and `COMPILE-FILE` are standard Common Lisp functions.

**Creating applications**

A few definitions:

- *CCL kernel*: the part of CCL which provides low-level runtimes services like memory management.
- *Image*: a saved dump of the Lisp heap
- *Application*: CCL kernel + image. This can be in one file.

You can save an application by calling a CCL specific function:

```
(save-application "/foo/bar-image" :toplevel-function #'main)
```

This will save an image, that you can run using the CCL kernel from a command shell:

```
ccl -I /foo/bar-image
```

To save an executable that includes the kernel use this from Lisp:

```
(save-application "/foo/bar-app"
                  :toplevel-function #'main
                  :prepend-kernel t)
```

You can call this executable as usual with `/foo/bar-app` from a command shell.

In Clozure Common Lisp you can check

```
*command-line-argument-list*
```

for the list of provided command line arguments.

Comment: Fixed the mistake.

Also, the application was created as expected, but when I tried to load the exe an error message told me that the "Program too big to fit in memory". Have you run into this before? Know of a fix?

Comment: see my edit, use prepend-kernel to add the kernel to the file

Comment: I was testing all of this on their Windows Implementation and received the various errors mentioned. I just tested it on a Linux machine and it all works as expected. Thanks.

Comment: make sure you have the latest version of CCL on Windows (update from the repository). If that does not work, don't hesitate to report this as a bug on the CCL mailing list or their bugtracker.

Comment: The "Saving Applications" link at the top is incorrect or out of date.

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: fixed, but it is likely to break again, since the link contains the chapter number - which can change over time.